# Directive is not acting the way i want to - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created two custom directives, one parent and one child directive that communicate with each other through parent directive controller.

---

**Parent Directive**

```
app.directive('attrsCtrl', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        attributes: '=array',
        options: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.attributes = [];

        this.returnOptions = function(){
            return $scope.options;
        }

        this.saySomething = function (obj) {
            $scope.attributes.push(obj);
            alert(obj.name + "/" + obj.type.name);

            var newDirective = angular.element('<attributes> </attributes>');
            $element.append(newDirective);
            $compile(newDirective)($scope);
        }
    }
}})
```

---

**Child Directive**

```
app.directive('attributes', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^attrsCtrl',
    template: '<div ng-class="classInput">' +
        '   <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0;">' +
        '       <label>Nome do Atributo</label>' +
        '       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Nome do Atributo" ng-model="attrname" ng-change="validation()" ng-disabled="afterSend">' +
        '   </div>' +
        '   <div class="col-md-4 " style="padding-left: 0;"> ' +
        '       <label>Tipo do Atributo</label> ' +
        '           <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-options="option.name for option in options" ng-model="attrtype" ng-disabled="afterSend"></select>' +
        '   </div> ' +
        '   <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-right: 0;"> ' +
        '    <label>  </label>' +
        '           <button type="button" class=" btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="changeButton()" style="margin-top: 1em;" ng-disabled="disabled"> Adicionar </button>' +
        '   </div> ' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="clearfix></div>',

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, attrsCtrl) {
        scope.classInput = 'form-group';
        scope.disabled = true;
        scope.afterSend = false;
        scope.options = attrsCtrl.returnOptions();


        scope.changeButton = function () {
            scope.attr = {
                name: scope.attrname,
                type: scope.attrtype
            };
            attrsCtrl.saySomething(scope.attr);
            scope.disabled = true;
            scope.afterSend = true;
        }

        scope.validation = function () {
            if (scope.attrname.length < 6) {
                scope.classInput = 'form-group has-error';
            } else {
                scope.classInput = 'form-group has-success';
                scope.disabled = false;
            }
        }

    }
};})
```

---

**HTML**

```
 <attrs-ctrl array="myAttributes" options="options" >
          <attributes/>
 </attrs-ctrl>
```

My issue is that after i click twice to create a directive, it automatically creates another directive but i can't type anything in it! This behavior was supposed to happen only after i click on "Adicionar" button.

Comment: unrelated, but change `<attributes/>` to `<attributes></attributes>` as AngularJS doesn't like closed tags.

Comment: Dont know what u want to do... may be my example will help u:http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQmarVcyLWo5Q6iMbVcb?p=info

Comment: I would **seriously** recommend using templateURL rather than template with your directive.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here

1. In above example, `link` function contains `scope.disabled = true;`, it should be changed to `scope.disabled = false;` I guess it is your typo while pasting the example here.
2. Secondly, I guess you have added the parent directive dependency explicitly as you want to create independent child directive. As per your code, the scope between parent and child directive is getting shared. So, scope of parent directive is being shared across all child directives and all fields are appearing disabled.

Add `scope:{},` to your directive function as given below...
This will create separate child directive `scope`.

There is a nice article explaining scopes in details: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

```
app.directive('attributes', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^attrsCtrl',
    scope: {},
    template: '<div ng-class="classInput">' +
        '   <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0;">' +
        '       <label>Nome do Atributo</label>' +
        '       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Nome do Atributo" ng-model="attrname" ng-change="validation()" ng-disabled="afterSend">' +
        '   </div>' +
        '   <div class="col-md-4 " style="padding-left: 0;"> ' +
        '       <label>Tipo do Atributo</label> ' +
        '           <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-options="option.name for option in options" ng-model="attrtype" ng-disabled="afterSend"></select>' +
        '   </div> ' +
        '   <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-right: 0;"> ' +
        '    <label>  </label>' +
        '           <button type="button" class=" btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="changeButton()" style="margin-top: 1em;" ng-disabled="disabled"> Adicionar </button>' +
        '   </div> ' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="clearfix></div>',

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, attrsCtrl) {
        scope.classInput = 'form-group';
        scope.disabled = false;
        scope.afterSend = false;
        scope.options = attrsCtrl.returnOptions();


        scope.changeButton = function () {
            scope.attr = {
                name: scope.attrname,
                type: scope.attrtype
            };
            attrsCtrl.saySomething(scope.attr);
            scope.disabled = true;
            scope.afterSend = true;
        }

        scope.validation = function () {
            console.log("validate");
            if (scope.attrname.length < 6) {
                scope.classInput = 'form-group has-error';
            } else {
                scope.classInput = 'form-group has-success';
                scope.disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
};})
```